# How to use factories to generate an object of a template class with a specific type?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, polymorphism

I am working on a project that requires me to create a factory for a templated class. The class hierarchy I've come up with so far looks like this:

```
class base {
  public:
  static base* create_object(string type){
    if (type=="int"){
      base* ptr = new derived<int>;
      return ptr;
    }else if (type=="float"){
      base* ptr = new derived<float>;
      return ptr;
    }
  }
};

template <class T>
class derived : public base{
  public:
  T data;
};
```

The idea is that the type is given by a config file that is read at the beginning, so the types are given at compile time and can't change afterwards. The base class should act as a factory to generate objects of a specific data type.

My problem is that eventually I will need to access the `data` member, but I can't do with the pointer to a base class object. I could just make `base` virtual and then use `dynamic_cast`. But I don't think that would be considered good practice because `base` doesn't have any virtual functions and I don't need any of them here. I just want to access `data`.

So my question then is: How do I best do this?

Comment: How do you plan to access it? Give an example. You can't do `int x = ptr->data;` because it might be a string, you can't do `string x = ptr->data;` because it might be an int. So I'm curious how you expect to use it.

Comment: See, here: everyone has their own definition of how to "best do this". This is entirely opinion-based, what's "best". I would, for example, suggest scrapping the whole design based on a base class and derived class, and instead use a `std::variant`. I was going to suggest that as an answer, actually. However it is unclear whether the base class-based approach is needed for some other reason, in which case my answer will turn out to be a waste of time.

Comment: Tell me if the dupe is wrong